# How do I stop my iOS device from ringing for incoming Microsoft Teams app calls?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

My iPhone rings every time I receive a work Teams call, even though I have notifications disabled at the operating system level.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Settings app
2. Tap on Teams (almost all the way at the bottom of the main page)
3. Toggle on notifications.

[image: turn on notifications]

4. Open the Teams app
5. Tap your profile picture in the top left
6. Tap `Notifications`.

[image: Tap notifications]

7. Tap `General activity`
8. Toggle `Calls` off

[image: Toggle calls off]

9. Go back to Settings app and turn notifications for Teams off
10. Relax! No more ringing on your phone.